# Creating and Pasting Formula in VBA with Changing Cell Reference

Tags: excel, vba

I need to create a formula that is going to concatenate 3 different cells into one date. The formula is going to be a part of a loop function so I need the cell reference to change as the loop function runs.

I am having trouble with the syntax such as the "&" and the """" that are necessary to distinguish parts of the formula from the cell references.

For now I am just trying to get the formula to paste into a single cell without the loop. The 3 cells that I am combining are in columns: N,O & P. I am trying to paste the formula into column M.

I tried creating the formula on a separate "Data" tab and then simply copy and pasting it into each cell using VBA but the row number does not update according to the row that the formula is pasted.

I tried rearranging the & and "" for a while and could not figure out the winning combination.

```
FormulaRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

M_Formula = "=N" & FormulaRow & "" / "" & "O" & FormulaRow & "" / "" & "P" & FormulaRow

Range("M" & FormulaRow).Value = M_Formula
```

I am expecting to get the following result: =N5&"/"&O5&"/"&P5 with the row number corresponding to the row that the formula is pasted.

When I tried the copy and paste method I got this message: "Object Doesn't Support this Property or Method"

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Don't use concatenation to try to build up a date. Use the `DATE` function, manipulating your source columns as needed. Also - you don't need a loop to write a formula to a range. If the formula has relative references, Excel will update the row numbers for you.

Comment: To answer the question asked: `& "" / "" &` should be `& """/""" &`.

Comment: whats wrong with `ROW()` to return the row number?

Comment: Either try `Range("M" & FormulaRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=rc[1] & " & Chr(34) & "\" & Chr(34) & " & rc[2] & " & Chr(34) & "\" & Chr(34) & " & rc[3]"` or try
`Range("M" & FormulaRow).Formula = "=N" & FormulaRow & " & " & Chr(34) & "\" & Chr(34) & " & O" & FormulaRow & " & " & Chr(34) & "\" & Chr(34) & " & P" & FormulaRow`. Though thought not suitable for date but found working with date also.

Comment: As commented by @Bigben, it would be preferable to use Date function like `Range("M" & FormulaRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=date(rc[3] ,rc[2] ,rc[1])"`  or  `Range("M" & FormulaRow + 1).Formula = "=date(P" & FormulaRow & ",O" & FormulaRow & ",N" & FormulaRow & ")"`

Answer (score 0):

Excel is smart enough to increment the row reference when you do a range in one go:

```
Range("M5:M" & Range("N" & rows.count).end(xlup).row).formula = "=N5 & ""/"" & O5 & ""/"" & P5"
```

That will do what you want in 1 line.

Then you can copy the result, paste as values then format to date with something like this:

```
Sub EnterDate()
    Range("M5:M" & Range("N" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Formula = "=N5 & ""/"" & O5 & ""/"" & P5"
    Range("M5:M" & Range("N" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Copy
    Range("M5:M" & Range("N" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Range("M5:M" & Range("N" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).NumberFormat = "DD/MM/YYYY"
    'Force a reevaluate to make it see actual dates
    Range("M5:M" & Range("N" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Formula = Range("M5:M" & Range("N" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value
End Sub
```

Using this method I just tested on over 12,000 rows and it took under a second.

With regards to the comments about using the date function, using the date function is a much better method, I wanted to show you how to do it using your own method but you can get rid of the formatting code if you use Date like so:

```
Sub EnterDate()
    Range("M5:M" & Range("N" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Formula = "=DATE(P5,O5,N5)"
    Range("M5:M" & Range("N" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Copy
    Range("M5:M" & Range("N" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

If you want to leave the formulas then simply delete the last 2 lines in there.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
Sub sub1()
' If you have 12 in N2 and 34 in O2 and 5678 in P2:
  Dim FormulaRow&, M_Formula$
  FormulaRow = 2
  M_Formula = "=N" & FormulaRow & "&" & """" & "/" & """" & "&" & _
               "O" & FormulaRow & "&" & """" & "/" & """" & "&" & _
               "P" & FormulaRow
  Cells(FormulaRow, ColNum("M")) = M_Formula ' gives the formula you want 12/34/5678
  Cells(FormulaRow, 13) = M_Formula ' also gives the formula you want 12/34/5678
End Sub

Function ColNum&(col$)
  ColNum = Range(col & 1).Column
End Function
```